# what is the most elegant way to update an item in one list from another list in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 collections and i have the following code to loop through one collection and see if it exists in another collection.  If it does exist, then update a property of that item.

```
        foreach (var favorite in myFavoriteBooks)
        {
            var book = allBooks.Where(r => r.Name == favorite.Name).FirstOrDefault();

            if (book != null)
            {
                book.IsFavorite = true;
            }
        }
```

Is there a more elegant or faster way to achieve this code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Join` for this, either in extension method syntax or LINQ syntax:

Extension method:

```
foreach(var favorite in myFavoriteBooks.Join(allBooks, 
                                             f => f.Name, 
                                             a => a.Name, 
                                            (f, a) => a))
{
    a.IsFavorite = true;
}
```

LINQ:

```
var favorites = from f in myFavoriteBooks
                join a in allBooks on f.Name equals a.Name
                select a

foreach(var favorite in favorites)
{
    favorite.IsFavorite = true;
}
```

These solutions are functionally identical; they differ only by syntax and they are faster than your original solution, since LINQ will build a hashtable on both sides and use that for matching rather than scanning the other list for every item in the original list.

Answer (score 3):

You can more easily find the books in one collection that match another collection with `Any`

```
var booksInCommon = allBooks.Where(b => myFavoriteBooks.Any(bi => bi.Name == b.Name));
foreach(book b in booksInCommon)
   b.IsFavorite = true;
```

Or, if you don't mind "tricky" code

```
allBooks.Where(b => myFavoriteBooks.Any(bi => bi.Name == b.Name)).ToList()
    .ForEach(b => b.IsFavorite = true);
```

**EDIT**

As Adam Robinson points out, this is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, so avoid it if you have thousands of books in both of your collections and opt for his Join answer.

Comment: While I wouldn't recommend this particular approach, it seems that your collections are reversed (it should be `allBooks.Where` and `myFavoriteBooks.Any`)

Comment: Thanks @Adam!  Hopefully a few nice new badges will be sufficient thanks.  So why wouldn't you recommend this?  Isn't this a common idiom in linq?

Comment: Unlike modern RDBMS's, LINQ doesn't have anything like a query optimizer, so how you put the query together can make a *huge* impact. This solution is O(N^2), as you have to scan list A for every item in list B (you're essentially creating a cartesian product). Using something like `Join` (see my answer) will create a hashtable, meaning that each side is scanned exactly one time, then the hashtables are used for the actual matching, making the operation O(N). This, combined with the fact that using `Join` is more intuitive (for me) is why I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - ahh, fair enough.  I added an edit to warn OP of this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the books collections were stored in dictionaries with the key of Name, then this becomes an easy and very efficient operation:

```
        var myFavoriteBooks = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, book>();
        var allBooks = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, book>();

        foreach (var bookName in myFavoriteBooks.Keys)
        {
            if (allBooks.ContainsKey(bookName))
            {
                allBooks[bookName].IsFavorite = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var favTitles = new HashSet<string>(favorite.Select(f => f.Name));
//favTitles now a hash-based O(1) name lookup.
foreach(var book in allBooks.Where(b => favTitles.Contains(b.Name)))
  book.IsFavorite = true;
```